In Mutant Year Zero, how does the Counselor talent interact with the Chronicler's Inspire skill when you help others?
In Mutant Year Zero, when you help others you give them a +1 modifier (+1d6).
If you have the Counselor talent, the person you help gets an extra +1 modifier (+1d6) (if he is doing something you told him to do).
But the Chronicler's Inspire skill replaces the normal help eﬀect for:

When using this skill, you can give all of your rolled 6s to the person you are helping. It counts as if he had rolled them himself, and he simply adds them to the 6s he did roll.

So my question is, what happens to the additional +1 modifier from the Counselor talent when a Chronicler helps others?

Buenas, Federico!  I reformatted your question to be more in line with standard English usage, but I am unfamiliar with Mutant Year Zero.  Please look it over and make sure it is still representing what you wanted to ask.  You can re-edit or even rollback if you do not think so.
